Limits of arbitrary polynomials divided by constants greater than 1 raised to the power of n
Problem statement:
Prove that for any $a > 1$ and any polynomial $p(x)$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{p(n)}{a^n} =0 
\end{align*}
Solution:
We need to use squeeze theorem and consider this expression as a sequence.
The goal to show that:
\begin{align*}
c_n \leq \dfrac{p(n)}{a^n} \leq d_n \\
\text{where} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}c_n =0 \text{ and }\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}d_n =0
\end{align*}
For some arbitrary sequences $c_n$ and $d_n$. 
consider $p(n)$ having some finite degree $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{align*}
p(n) = b_kn^k + b_{k-1}n^{k-1}+ ... + b_1n+b_0  
\end{align*}

Lemma:
For any $a \in (-1,1)$ and $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^ka^n =0
\end{align*}
proof:
when $a=0$, the result is trivial. consider $0<a<1$. Write:
\begin{align*}
 a = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} = \frac{1}{1+b} 
\end{align*}
Where $\dfrac{1}{a} > 1$ and $b = \dfrac{1}{a} - 1 > 0$. Using the binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}
a^n &= \dfrac{1}{(1+b)^n} = \dfrac{1}{1 + nb + C^n_2 b^2+...+C^n_{n-1}b^{n-1} +b^n} \\
n^ka^n &= \dfrac{n^k}{1 + nb + C^n_2 b^2+...+C^n_{n-1}b^{n-1} +b^n} 
\end{align*}
WLOG assume $n>k$ hence we have:
\begin{align*}
 n^ka^n &= \dfrac{n^k}{1 + nb + C^n_2 b^2+...+C^n_{k+1}b^{k+1}+...+C^n_{n-1}b^{n-1} +b^n} 
\end{align*}
Observe that:
\begin{align*}
 C^n_{k+1} &= \dfrac{n!}{(n-k -1)!(k+1)!} = \dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k)}{(k+1)!}\\ 
 \implies \dfrac{n^k}{C^n_{k+1}} &= \dfrac{(k+1)!}{n(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{k}{n})}
\end{align*}
Now because:
\begin{align*}
 C^n_{k+1}b^{k+1} \leq  1 + nb + C^n_2 b^2+...+C^n_{k+1}b^{k+1}+...+C^n_{n-1}b^{n-1} +b^n 
 \end{align*}
We have:
\begin{align*}
 n^ka^n = \dfrac{n^k}{1 + nb + C^n_2 b^2+...+C^n_{n-1}b^{n-1} +b^n} \leq \dfrac{n^k}{C^n_{k+1}} = \dfrac{(k+1)!}{n(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{k}{n})}\\
 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\dfrac{(k+1)!}{n(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{k}{n})} = \dfrac{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(k+1)!}{n}}{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{2}{n})...\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{k}{n})}
\end{align*}
Because $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{k}{n} =0$ for any constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{align*}
  \dfrac{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(k+1)!}{n}}{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{2}{n})...\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac{k}{n})} = \dfrac{(k+1)! \times 0}{(1-0)(1-0)...(1-0)} =0
\end{align*}
Hence, we can indeed bound $n^ka^n$ above and below. $n^ka^n$ has a trivial lower bound of $0$, as here we consider $0<a<1$:
\begin{align*}
0\leq  n^ka^n \leq \dfrac{n^k}{C^n_{k+1}} \\
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}0 =0 ,\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n^k}{C^n_{k+1}} =0\\
\implies \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^ka^n =0 \text{ by squeeze theorem for } a \in (0,1)
\end{align*}
For the negative case where $a \in (-1,0)$ consider:
\begin{align*}
-|n^ka^n| \leq n^ka^n \leq |n^ka^n| = n^k|a^n| =n^k|a|^n
\end{align*}
Because we have already proved that for $a \in (0,1)$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n^ka^n =0$:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^k|a|^n &=0 \\
\implies \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}-|n^ka^n| &=0  \\
\text{by the squeeze theorem, } \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^ka^n &=0 \qquad \text{for } \quad a \in (-1,0)
\end{align*}
Hence, for any $a \in (-1,1)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^ka^n =0
\end{align*}

Now back to the main proof.
For a polynomial $p(n)$ of some degree $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $a >1$:
\begin{align*}
 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{p(n)}{a^n} &=  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{b_kn^k + b_{k-1}n^{k-1}+ ... + b_1n+b_0}{a^n}\\
 &=  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left[ \dfrac{b_k}{a^n}n^k +\dfrac{b_{k-1}}{a^n}n^{k-1} +...+\dfrac{b_1}{a^n}n+\dfrac{b_0}{a^n} \right]
\end{align*}
consider any index $j \in (0,k)$
\begin{align*}
 b_j\dfrac{1}{a^n}n^j = b_j\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^nn^j \qquad \because a>1 \implies \frac{1}{a} <1 \text{ and } \frac{1}{a} \in (-1,1)\\
 \implies \text{from the lemma} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  b_j\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^nn^j = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}b_j \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^nn^j = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}b_j \times 0 =0
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left[ \dfrac{b_k}{a^n}n^k +\dfrac{b_{k-1}}{a^n}n^{k-1} +...+\dfrac{b_1}{a^n}n+\dfrac{b_0}{a^n} \right] &=0+0+...+0+0\\
 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{p(n)}{a^n} &=0
\end{align*}
Queries:

Is this a valid proof?
Are there more elegent ways to prove this, specifically using the properties of limits, sequences and/or polynomials?

PS: This is not a homework question

Are you familiar with the ratio test?

Thought the ratio test is applicable for series.

There is another ratio test for sequences: namely, if $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive terms, then if $\lim \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L>1$ then $a_n\to+\infty$ and if $\lim \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L<1$ then $a_n\to 0$.

With this, I can think of trying to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^ka^{n+1}}{n^ka^n} =L < 1$, but this would be unwieldy, still needing the binomial expansion of $(n+1)^k$

There is no need for binomial expansion, see my answer.

An easier way: if the degree of the polynomial is $k$, it is clear that, dividing both numerator or denominator by $n^k$, the result is equivalent to \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a^n}{n^k}=+\infty \tag{1}\end{equation}
But we have $$\dfrac{\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)^k}}{\dfrac{a^n}{n^k}}=a\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^k\to a>1$$
Therefore, by the ratio test $(1)$ follows and so the original result does too.

So your claim is that: $\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac{p(n)}{a^n} =0$ where $p(n)$ has a degree of $k$ is equivalent to proving $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{a^n}{n^k} = +\infty$?
Why not prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n^k}{a^n} = 0$?
Then we can see that $\frac{\frac{(n+1)^k}{a^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^k}{a^n}} = (1+\frac{1}{n})^k \times \frac{1}{a}$ and because $a >1$, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^k \times \frac{1}{a} < 1$

The two limits are exactly the same, one is the reciprocal of the other (and the last limit is $1/a$, not $0$)

Sure, but we would need to show that any polynomial $p(n)$ of degree $k$ can be reduced to $n^k$

No. Divide both numerator and denominator by $n^k$. The numerator will tend to the principal coefficient of $p(x)$ and in the denominator we have $a^n/n^k$, which I have proven to diverge.

Alright, now I see your argument

For all $x \ge 1$,
$
\displaystyle \left| \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {a}_{k} {x}^{k} \right| \le \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \left| {a}_{k} \right| {x}^{k} \le \sum_{k = 0}^{n} A {x}^{k} \le \left( n + 1 \right) A {x}^{n} \tag*{}
$
where $A = \max_{0 \le k \le n} \left| {a}_{k} \right|$, and
$
\displaystyle \frac {{x}^{n}}{{e}^{c x}} = \frac {{x}^{n}}{\sum_{k \ge 0} {\left( c x \right)}^{k} / k!} \le \frac {{x}^{n}}{{\left( c x \right)}^{n + 1} / \left( n + 1 \right)!} = \frac {\left( n + 1 \right)!}{{c}^{n + 1} x}. \tag*{}
$
Since
$
\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {1}{x} = 0, \tag*{}
$
we know
$
\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {{x}^{n}}{{e}^{c x}} = 0 \tag*{}
$
for all $c > 0$, and
$
\displaystyle \boxed {\lim_{x \to \infty} {e}^{- c x} \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {a}_{k} {x}^{k} = 0.} \tag*{}
$

Could you expand on how $e^{-cx}$ is equivalent to $a^{-x}$ ? where $a >1$?

@RagemprandHrekt, let $c = \ln \left( a \right)$.

Alright, I see this now: with $a^x = e^{x\ln{a}}$, we can use the infinite series representation of $e^{cx}$

Let $M$ denote the sum of absolute values of the coefficients of $P(x).$ Then $|P(n)|\le Mn^k,$ where $k$ is the degree of $P(x).$ Let $a=1+b,$ where $b>0.$ Then $a^k=(1+b)^n\ge {n\choose k+1}b^k.$ Thus $${|P(n)|\over a^n}\le {M(k+1)!\over b^k}{\,n^k\over (n-k)(n-k+1)\cdot\ldots \cdot n}\\ \le {M^k(k+1)!\over b^k}\left({n\over n-k}\right)^k{1\over n}$$ The limit of RHS is $0.$
